# moment.js date in Django template

Tags: javascript, python, django, momentjs

I want to display the date of the relevant text (for example, 3 days ago) using the moment.js. But my code does not work.

My code, but it does not work:

```
<div class="base">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var time = {{ obj.pub_date|date:'Ymd' }};
        moment(time, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
    </script>
    <p>{{ obj.text }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: First, `moment(time, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()` will return something which you will have to assign to something. Then you will have to set as text in `p` **using javascript**

Comment: Wokrs, thank you very much :) @Rajesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not assigning whatever is returned from your .fromNow() call to a variable, or doing anything with it.